# Functional independence

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, definition

Definition confusion:

I wish to show that $$f(x,y)={-y\over x}$$ and $$g(x,y)=\log |x|$$ are *functionally independent* on some domain.

What does that mean? What do I have to show? And how does one choose the domain?

Thank you.

---

This is related to question 2 on P. 84 in [this book](http://www.scribd.com/doc/75041721/Maciej-Dunajski-Solitons-Instantons-and-Twistors). In particular, the note in the square brackets. However, I don't know what exactly that is and why we would like to do that.

Comment: Why do you wish to show it?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: This is related to question 2 on P. 84 in [this book](http://www.scribd.com/doc/75041721/Maciej-Dunajski-Solitons-Instantons-and-Twistors). In particular, the note in the square brackets. However, I don't know what exactly that is and why we would like to do that.

Comment: The book link works, but doesn't have the book anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the gradients $\nabla{f},\nabla{g}$ are linearly independed in that domain. i.e. the Jacobian $J_F$ of the function $F(x,y)=(f(x,y),g(x,y))$ has full rank. 
So calculate $J_F$ and find the domain such that $\operatorname{rank}{(J_f)}=2 $.

Comment: What about when $F(x,y,z) = (f(x,y,z),g(x,y,z))$? The Jacobian is then 2-by-3. Thanks!

Comment: In that case we want the Jacobian to have rank $2$. In any case we want the Jacobian to have rank equal to the number of the functions.

Comment: @P.. "_we want the Jacobian to have rank equal to the number of the functions_" Why does that mean the functions are functionally independent?

Comment: @Geremia: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110763/intuition-behind-functional-dependence

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the book **Holomorphic Morse Inequalities and Bergmann Kernels(p.103)**, I think it means that if there are $a,b\in\mathbb R$, such that
$$af+bg=0,$$
we have $a=b=0$.