# Intuition behind functional dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, intuition

What is the intuition behind *functional independence* ?

(This is defined in the following way: Let $k\leq n$. The $C^1$ functions $F_1,\ldots,F_k:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are functionally independent if the matrix whose columns are the gradients  $\nabla F_1,\ldots,\nabla F_k$ has full rank, i.e. rank $k$, on the whole domain of definition.

From what I gather from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48306/jacobian-matrix-rank-and-dimension-of-the-image) answer, this is the same as saying that $F:=(F_1,\ldots,F_k):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ is submersion, but that doesn't help me much either, because I also don't have any intuition concerning submersions.)

So what does it really *mean* if the functions are functional indepedent - or conversely, dependent ? Is there, in the latter case, then also a relationship like $g(\nabla F_1,\ldots,\nabla F_k)=0$ -- or maybe like $g(F_1(x),\ldots F_k (x))=0$ for some $x$ -- for $g$ ranging in some specific set, similar to the case of linear independence ( in which $g$ would be from the set $\{g:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:g(x_1,\ldots,x_k)=\sum \lambda_i x_i \text{ for some nonzero } \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$).

Comment: What if the gradients don't exist? It's implicit in your assumption, why not mention it from the outset, eg $C^1$ or similar

Comment: @alancalvitti if the gradients don't exist, we can't speak of functional dependence. but for completeness I added the $C^1$ assupmption in the post.

Comment: Functional dependence means left-total and single-valued relation. Differential structure is not part of the definition.

Comment: @alancalvitti Then you know more about functional dependence than I do...could you please explain your definition in more detail, as I e.g. do not know, what you mean by left-total ? Maybe you could make that an answer, as I have the impression, that you have a deeper understand of functional (in)dependence (and how it generalizes linear (in)dependence) and the answer already give does not yet cover all concerns.

Comment: Check the table here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_algebra - functional is the first item. Functions need not be differentiable or even continuous, but need to be defined everywhere ("left total", or simply "total", or "preserving elements") and the image of each element of a function is also a single element of the codomain ("single valued" or "reflecting distinctions").

Comment: @alancalvitti are you sure that this very abstract definition of functional dependence really specialize to my definition of functional dependence for differentiable functions ? Because of the nature of this very general definitino, I'm a bit sceptic if we're not talking about different things here...If one can indeed recover the definition, could you indicate the boolean algebra in which I can recover my definition of differentiability ?

Comment: Yes, a continuous, differentiable function is still a function. For example, Jittorntrum's Implicit Function Theorem (J Opt Th App 1978) does not assume differentiability: if a continuous function $F(x,y)$ is locally  injective in some neighborhood of a point, then $F(x,y)=0$ has a unique solution $x=G(y)$ with $G$ also continuous. I don't think there's a combinatorial proof w/o continuity assumption though.

Comment: @alancalvitti While I don't doubt that a differentiable (and thus continuous) function is a function and your reference is interesting, I don't see what this has to do with showing that the definition of functional dependence, as in the case of a boolean algebra, can be made to agree with the definition I wrote in my question above. (For an answer to that, one would have to provide a specific set [of functions] together with some unary and binary relations and show that it is a boolean alebgra and then show that the boolean-algebra-definition recovers my definition above. )

Comment: I didn't assume anything that you didn't assume, since $C^1$ is a subcategory of $C^0$ which is in turn a subcat of $Set$, the category of sets and functions.

Comment: To all the other answerers: I wish I could have split the bounty in three, because every answer did add a (different) bit of intuition! But Blatters was the the moste complete and thus easiest to read and also the only one to attract me to the problem that there is an incompatibility between dependence and independence and therefore I ultimately chose to award him the award.

Comment: Goursat's [*A Course in Mathematical Analysis* (vol. 1) pp. 52](https://archive.org/stream/coursemathanalys01gourrich#page/n67/mode/2up)ff. proves that the functional determinant being zero is a necessary and sufficient condition for functional independence.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Functional dependence* of $k$ given functions $F_i:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb R}$ $\>(1\leq i\leq k)$ with common domain $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ means, intuitively, that there is a nontrivial function
$$g:\quad{\mathbb R}^k\to{\mathbb R},\qquad y\mapsto g(y)$$
such that
$$g\bigl(F_1(x),F_2(x),\ldots, F_k(x)\bigr)\equiv 0\qquad \forall x\in\Omega\ .\tag{1}$$
"Nontrivial" for $g$ means that $\nabla g(y)\ne0$ for all $y\in{\mathbb R}^k$.
Taking the derivative of $(1)$ we see that
$$dg\bigl(F(x)\bigr)\cdot dF(x)\equiv 0\in{\cal L}({\mathbb R}^n,{\mathbb R}^k)\qquad\forall x\in\Omega\ .$$
In terms of matrices this says that the rows of the matrix $\bigl[dF(x)\bigr]$ are linearly dependent with coefficients given by $\nabla g\bigl(F(x)\bigr)\ne0$, for each $x\in\Omega$.

Now the rows of the matrix $\bigl[dF(x)\bigr]$ are nothing else but the gradients $\nabla F_i(x)$. Therefore functional dependence of the $F_i$ in the above sense implies that the gradients $\nabla F_i(x)$ are linearly dependent, **at each point** $x\in\Omega$.

In your definition of "functional independence"  you don't want even a hint of such a thing. Therefore you insist that **at all points** $x\in\Omega$  the $k$ gradients $\nabla F_i(x)$ should be linearly independent.

Comment: So functional independence of $k$ functions should actually mean the negation of your definition, i.e. that there **exists** an $x_0\in \Omega$ such that the $k$ gradients are independent ?

Comment: @user36772: There is indeed a gap between the idea of functional dependence and your definition of functional independence.

Comment: Could you maybe give me an reference where a definition of functional (in)dependence can be found, so that I have something official to quote, when referring to the definition ?

Comment: The following are two (well seasoned) papers dealing with these notions: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/WFNewns.pdf   ,  http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1935-038-02/S0002-9947-1935-1501816-5/S0002-9947-1935-1501816-5.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Functional independence between two functions means that the level set of each of the functions intersects transversely the level set of the other function. In the plane, this means that a function $f$ functionally independent of another function $g$ cannot be written as $f=F(g)$ where $F$ is another function, because in this case, the level sets would be the same curves, for both $f$ and $g$. Similarly, in $k$ dimensions, functional independence means that the intersection between the $k$ $(k-1)$-dimensional level sets of the $k$ functions is a point, not a line or a plane, i. e., the functions $F_1$, $F_2$,...,$F_k$ contains $k$ independent informations of your ambient space, and can be taken locally as coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $F$ is $DF=[\nabla F_1,\cdots,\nabla F_k]^T$ ; let $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $b=F(a)$ and $V=F^{-1}(b)$. $V$ is the intersection of the $k$ hypersurfaces $F_i(x)=b_i$. The normal vector in $a$ to such a hypersurface is $\nabla F_i(a)\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Here $rank(DF_a)=k$, that is $W=span(\nabla F_1(a),\cdots,\nabla F_k(a))$ has dimension $k$. According to the implicit function theorem, in a neighborhhood of $a$, $V$ is a variety of dimension $n-k$, that is $V$ is $C^1$-isomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$. Moreover the tangent space of $V$ in $a$ is the orthogonal of $W$.

For instance, let $n=3,k=2$. $V$ is the intersection of $2$ surfaces in the standard space. The normal vectors $u_1,u_2$ in $a$ are not parallel ; then $V$ is locally a line and the cross product $u_1\times u_2$ is tangent to this line.

EDIT 1. In other words, an approximation of the equation of $V$ is $DF_a(x-a)=0$, that is, for every $i\leq k$, $<\nabla F_i(a),x-a>=0$.

@ user36772 , I just read your last four lines ! You speak about the case when (in my instance) the $2$ previous normals are parallel. Then the surfaces are tangent in $a$ and we know nothing about the intersection. In other words, when the hypothesis of a theorem are not satisfied, then (is it surprising ?) the theorem does not work.

EDIT 2. (answer to user36772). A level set is a subvariety of codimension $1$, that is an hypersurface.

The tangent space to an hypersurface is the hyperplane that is orthogonal to a normal vector ; then the tangent space to $V$ is the intersection of these hyperplanes. From the geometrical point of view, to say that the $C^1$ functions are independent in a neighborhood of $a$ is equivalent to identify each hypersurface with its tangent hyperplane in $a$ and to say that the linear equations associated to these hyperplanes are linearly independent. This property is stable in the following sense: if we move slightly our hypersurfaces, then the intersection remains similar to the original one.

If these equations are not linearly independent, then the instability comes at a gallop. For instance, consider, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $a=0, F_1=y-x^2,F_2=y-x^4$. Then, locally, the intersection of the surfaces is the line $Oz$. Yet, if you move one surface, then the intersection may be locally void.

Think also to the GPS ; we need $5$ satellites. Geometrically, the intersection of $3$ spheres suffice. Yet a fourth measure allows synchronization of clocks. Why the fifth ? Because if two among the satellites are "close", then the associated spheres are nearly tangent and the intersection is unstable.

Comment: I think you wanted to say that $V$ is the intersection of $k$ level sets, not hypersurfaces. Ok, I think I understood the local geometric interpretation of functional independence: In every point the preimage is an manifold of dimension $n-k$. But what that geometrically globally resp. algebraically means for the functions $F_1,...,F_k$ is still unclear to me - like linear independence would gometrically globally mean that vectors lie in the same plane and algebraically means that every linear combination, where at least some scalars are nonzero, is also nonzero.

Comment: (Specifically in your answer, if the normal vectors are parallel, could you explain a bit more formally why the urfaces have then to be tangent ? And which theorem do you the quote, that does nit work ?)

Comment: Linear independence is not defined for equations but for vectors, so I'm not sure what exactly you mean, when you say "linear equations associated to these hyperplanes are linearly independent". I suppose you wanted to say that hyperplanes are spanned by a finite number of vectors - but then its also unclear for me how to interpret linear independence in this case because linear independence isn't definite for multiple families/sets of vectors [each spanning on hyperplane], but just for one family/set of vectors. [...]

Comment: [...] One possibility to interpret your statement would thus be that you say that the family of vectors, obtained by collecting the vectors spanning *all* the hyperplanes, is linearly independent. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Also, concerning my last 4 lines ("functional dependence") from my question: Did I understood your answer right, that you meant that no such $g$ exists, such that $g(\nabla F_1,\ldots,\nabla F_k)=0$  ?

Comment: @ user36772 , You should read a book about linear algebra. The direction of an affine hyperplane is given by a linear form and the set of linear forms is a vector space. I did the job. Now your question is no more my business.